# SQL inner join Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I'm making a library system which allows student assistants to log in to the system. I have a table for student information to pull out information of the student assistants from instead of putting that same information in the student assistants accounts table because that would be a bit too redundant.

```
sqlSearch = "select * from tblSALogin where SA_ID = '" & txtUserName.Text & _
 "' inner join tblStudentInfo on tblSALogin.StudentID = tblStudentInfo.StudentID"
```

I'm using the above SQL query expression to do that but it gives me a missing operator error and i don't know why. The syntax of the expression is correct and all of the tables required for the expression have already been related and have the required records.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the `where` after the `join`:

```
sqlSearch = _
"select * from tblSALogin " & _
"inner join tblStudentInfo on tblSALogin.StudentID=tblStudentInfo.StudentID " & _
"where SA_ID = '" & txtUserName.Text & "'"
```

Also note that you are vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection#Blind_SQL_injection) with this query, and you should look into using parameterized queries.

Answer (score 0):

the join should be in the `FROM` clause, not in the `WHERE` clause

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this

```
sqlSearch = "select tblSALogin.*,tblStudentInfo.* from tblSALogin inner join tblStudentInfo on tblSALogin.StudentID = tblStudentInfo.StudentID where SA_ID = '" & txtUserName.Text &"' "
```

Where clause should be come after Join.